# Why does s.find return string::npos instead of s.length() on failure

Tags: c++, string, find

I recently was annoyed to find that `string::find` returns `string::npos` when the needle isn't found in the haystack. This makes the following seemingly-elegant code compile but throw an out-of-range exception:

```
s.erase(s.find('#')); // erase everything after a # if one exists
```

If `find` returned `s.length()` on failure, it would work fine. Instead you have to do

```
auto pos = s.find('#');
if (pos != s.npos)
    s.erase(pos);
```

This is also inconsistent with `std::find` which returns the end iterator if the item isn't found.

I know the standard people are pretty smart so I believe they didn't just come up with this out of nowhere. It must give some elegance somewhere else that I'm not seeing. What is the good reason for this?

Comment: Basically, you can test for not-being-contained-in without having to know the size of your data structure (which may not be trivially avialable).  While this could be done differently between different containers (those for which size is fast and those for which it isn't), it'd leave their interfaces inconsistent.  Finally, even in places where size is only a memory read, that memory read is still more expensive than returning the constant value `npos`.

Comment: +1. This post raises a really good question. `s.erase(s.find('#'))` would really be elegant only if `s.find()` would return `.size()` on failure.

Comment: @Nawaz Except that it would break backward compatibility instantly.

Comment: @creichen I think that is a weak argument because things like list, which don't (may not?) have their size easily available don't have a member `find`, and in their case they have `end` which is the same thing as `size` for `string`. Also avoiding checking `size` seems like a real micro optimization to me.

Comment: @uk4321 Micro-optimisations is what C++ is all about.  Otherwise the language spec wouldn't be the stuff of nightmares that it is today.

Comment: @creichen that's a highly dubious statement, and I still doubt that they were worried about a single memory read.

Comment: @ZacHowland: The question is about the design. I'm NOT asking to change it now. So the question of backward compatibility doesn't arise to begin with, if it were design like that.

Comment: It should also be noted that even if `std::string::find` returned `size()`, calling `s.erase(s.find('#'))` would be malformed for a string that does not contain `#`.  It would equate to `s.erase(s.size())`.  There are 3 overloads for `std::string::erase` - the only one that takes a `std::size_t` parameter is the one that takes a starting position and a length.  If you set the starting position to be passed the end of the string, you would be telling it to erase an element passed the end of the array.  You could not make this work without significant modifications to `std::string`.

Comment: @ZacHowland obviously the default second parameter would be changed to `size` as well so that's a non-issue.

Comment: @Nawaz The problem is:  it wasn't designed like that and there is a **ton** of code using the current interface.  If you change the interface, you break a **lot** of existing code.  Software Engineering Commandment #1:  Thou shall not change a published public interface.

Comment: @ZacHowland as Nawaz said, this question isn't "Why don't we change it" it's "Why did they make it that way in the first place".

Comment: @uk4321 As I said, you have to make significant changes to the interface.  So instead of a starting point and a length, you want a starting point and an ending point (that is what the iterator version does already).  Since the only reason the size_t version is there is for backward compatibility, you would basically remove the entire reason it is still there as you would be breaking it for existing code.

Comment: @ZacHowland: You misunderstood the question. It is NOT about changing the interface. It is about why it is designed like that. If you accept it is incorrectly designed, then I don't have anything to say, as I would agree with that.

Comment: @uk4321 The simple answer to that is because they were writing a fairly thin wrapper around the `string.h` functions.  The C-style string functions routinely dealt with a pointer and size.  Iterators were a concept that came around more with other STL containers that were being developed separately.

Comment: @ZacHowland this doesn't suggest using iterators though.

Comment: @uk4321 You are basically asking why they didn't treat the indexes like iterators.  That is, why didn't they create an erase function that looked like `void erase(std::size_t start, std::size_t end)` which would iterate from `start` to `end` to do the delete.  That answer is because the C-style functions they were wrapping dealt with the pointer and the length, not 2 indexes (treated like iterators).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about this: The original std::sting (STL) had no requirement to store the data contiguously. Hence, returning size() on failure in an operation would be an overhead (if the size is not stored). In c++11 strings are contiguous, and I agree to your critique.

Comment: Hmm that's interesting.

Comment: This answer makes *better* sense.

Comment: Does it really make sense? So `size()` might not be cached. You've just iterated over `size()` elements regardless. I'm not sure where that assumed overhead comes from.

Answer (score 11):

Your question is actually twofold:

> 1)  Why does `std::string` have it's own `find` function that returns
>   a `std::size_t` value instead of an iterator?

This is largely due to the fact that `std::string` was developed separately from much of the rest of the standard library.  It is only in recent standards that it has been embraced by other templates (e.g. iostream).  So when it was added to the standard, it had some functions added to it, but it's orginal functionality was left pretty much as-is (the exception being the common implemention of copy-on-write, which was forbidden in the C++11 standard).  It was left this way largely for backward-compatibility.

Per your question about why it was that way to begin with:  The original `string.h` was a very thin wrapper around several C string functions.  It was not at all uncommon to see `strlen` used as a return value for `length()`, or `strcpy` used in the copy constructor.  There was no requirement forcing the use of these functions, so eventually implementers started doing some *interesting* things (e.g. copy-on-write, non-contiguous memory blocks), but they left the interface the same to preserve backwards-compatibility.  While functions have been added to it, no public functions have been removed from the interface.  So you can trace the design decisions for using a pointer and length for function parameters back to the days when it was merely a wrapper around the C functions.

> 2) How can you write an erase sequence on a string without having to
>   check the return value?

This can be done simply by using the find-erase idiom, but not using `std::string`'s find function:

```
s.erase(std::find(s.begin(), s.end(), '#'), s.end());
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `std::string::npos` makes the result a constant expression unlike `std::string::length()`. Since `npos` isn't suitable as an iterator anyway there is value in having a constant expression, e.g., it can be used as default for parameters taking a `std::string::size_type`.

Another reason is that the basic interface for `std::basic_string` was put together before STL was added to the C++ standard library (well, at least, there is a part of the interface which existed then). The original interface was basically an immutable string and I think it didn't support any mutation of the string itself.

Comment: How does it matter if the return value is not constant expression? Returning `.size()` on no-found, makes more sense. It also looks similar to `std::find` which returns `.end()` on no-found.

Comment: @Nawaz: for example `std::basic_string<...>::substr()` has a defaulted second parameter with the value `std::basic_string<...>::npos`: defaulting it with the string's `length()` doesn't work, using the constant expression `npos` works a charm (... and can, e.g., be used to truncate a string up to a location found by a search using `str.substr(0, str.find('a'));`).

Comment: @DietmarKühl now that I think about it, that's not a very good reason either because you can do default arguments with just overloading, they could just do `auto substr(int pos) { return substr(pos, size()); }` right

Comment: @DietmarKühl: I'm not convinced. If `find()` returns `.size()` instead of `npos`, it is still possible to make `substr()` work as it is working now!

Comment: @Nawaz if `erase()` would accept `npos` as first parameter, that will solve the issue without side effects

Comment: @Nawaz: True. Unless you actually locate positions in a different string which is generally possible with index based operations. Using a special, known value, makes some things simpler. I'm not often playing with string manipulations but when using the string using its string interface it works quite smoothly (and it could be made really smooth if it could be assumed that `npos + 1 == 0` which is, unfortunately, not guaranteed).

Comment: @Nawaz: Besides the valid points that Dietmar raises, you can also consider that `std::find` *cannot* create an *npos-like* iterator, as that might not even exist. The algorithm `std::find` *needs* to return the `last` iterator, but in the case of `std::string` there is a well known value that can be returned instead.

Comment: @Slava: It was a deliberate choice to allow only valid positions as arguments to the various string operations while the length of the string is allowed to also support special "infinite" value (`npos`).

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: The question is, what if `std::string::find` returns `.size()`. As I understand, the well-known value `npos` doesn't help much, from elegance point of view.

Comment: @Nawaz: In the particular use case in the question it doesn't, but `std::string` has a bloated interface of close to 100 functions. Are you able to claim that over all of the interface the choice does not make it more elegant than the alternative? How many more overloads would be needed to support the equivalent of the default arguments?

Comment: @DietmarKühl probably, but changing behavior of `std::string::erase()`  such way at least does not invalidate valid existing code and makes it simple and elegant. Which is not the case of changing `std::string::find()` to return different value

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: I'm not claiming that (yet). I'm trying to understand it, rather than assuming `npos` to be elegant. So far I don't see `size()` idea is less elegant. I want to see a case where `.size()` idea would fail, or produce less elegant code.

Comment: @Slava: I guess, you won't much support in the committee for that! I'd claim that `str.erase(std::find(str, x));` works well enough (...and isn't there but I'd think eventually there will be range-based algorithms doing things like that).

Comment: @DietmarKühl yes that case will work, but something like str.erase( str.find_last_of( '#' ) ); is more complex.

Comment: @Slava: `str.erase(std::find(std::reverse_view(str)));` - sure, there are more complex needs. However, the string interface is bloated with things which should be non-members. That realization started to settle in with the event of STL being proposed (~1995). The string interface mainly precedes the introduction of STL.

Answer (score 0):

If you like behavior of `std::find` you should use it as `std::string` is a container:

```
s.erase( std::find( s.begin(), s.end(), '#' ), s.end() );
```

Changing s.find() behavior to return s.length() could make this particular case more elegant, but will make other problems. I think better solution would be to make std::string::erase() to accept std::string::npos as first parameter and do nothing.

Comment: That makes the case even more stronger that it would have been better if `std::string::find()` return `std::string::size()` on no-found. then you would be writing just `s.erase(s.find('#'));`. It is better, isn't it?

Comment: @Nawaz look to addition to my answer, I think tehere is better solution

Comment: The part *"but will make other problems"* does NOT help me! Could you point out what "other problems" are you talking about?

Comment: @Nawaz There is at least one problem that over-weights all other arguments - it will brake existing code. Enough? Or you need more?

Comment: @Slava imagine back in time when `string` didn't exist and they were designing it. There was no existing code. That is what we are talking about.

Comment: @uk4321 you are making decision based only on one case, but there are much more methods in `std::string`. Did you analize them all and really see that it is the better solution?

Comment: @Slava no, that's what this question is about. Have you?

Comment: @Slava: The discussion is NOT about changing the current interface, so the question of breaking existing code, doesn't arise. The question is  more like why it is designed like that in the first place?

Comment: @Nawaz: maybe they did not want to create 75 overrides just to make one call shorter by couple symbols?

Comment: @Slava: "maybe"? Is that your argument? Have you analyzed the other 75 functions which need to be override with this design?

Comment: @Nawaz I do not follow, you want answer to a question what if somebody made a different decision in the past, would that make this one particular call more elegant. So I need to analyze 75 function to answer your question? I do not care, especially there is easier solution that does not break anything

Comment: @Nawaz and I do not really see why idea of returning size() in case of failure is more elegant than to accept npos on erase. Can you explain that?

Comment: @Slava there are 15 functions that use npos as a default parameter, not 75.

Comment: @uk4321 15 is not enough? Again for this one particular case there is simplier solution and does not require any change of interface, why you insist of using size() ?

Comment: For the eighth time, this question is _not about changing the interface_. And this solution is not simpler.

Comment: OK not changing interface but creating 15 overrides. Why solution with size() is simpler than accepting npos in erase() ?

Comment: We don't care how simple it is to implement, we don't care that the implementors of the library have to write 60 more lines of code, this is about the interface, which will be used a billion times in code everywhere.

Comment: That not the answer why solution with size() is simpler.

Comment: ... You are mixing "simple for the clients" with "simple to implement." Are you talking about the clients now? Compare `s.erase(s.find(...))` which you could do with `size` with `s.erase( std::find( s.begin(), s.end(), ... ), s.end() );` or `auto pos = s.find(...);
if (pos != s.npos)
    s.erase(pos);`

Comment: @uk4321 you answered wrong question. I asked why your solution with size() is simplier than accepting npos in erase()?

Comment: Then sorry, I don't understand your question. What solution are you meaning, and why is it simpler than what exactly?

Comment: I described it in my answer, if std::string::erase() would accept std::string::npos as first parameter and do nothing that would solve your issue and would not require 15 overrides. Simple enough?

Comment: That would fix erase but not other things that you want to use find with, like substr for example, or other user-defined functions written to mimic string style. So you have to add `if (pos == string::npos)` to _every function you write_ instead of fixing the actual problem.

Comment: user-defined functions not a problem if they follow convinience with `npos`. substr() can follow erase() on accepting `npos` as first parameter. Is that not the same as change all functions to expect size() instead of `npos`?

Comment: @Slava no, if you use `size()` then you don't have to check. And adding the check to all functions adds up to a lot. Not to mention bugs can accidentally be hidden by ignoring when the first argument is npos.

Comment: So accessing size() in find() family and every time in user code you are checking for not found does not add at all in your mind, but comparing pos to npos adds a lot? I think you are biased towards your solution. And bugs accidentally ignoring that first parameter is npos are not the same as ignoring first parameter accidentally == size()?

Comment: No, with mine you do not need to check in the client code or the implementation. See how in `s.erase(s.find(...))` there is no check, not in the client code, nor in the implementor code. With your solution, you would have to add the check `if (pos != string::npos)` to the implementation of every function. As for bugs, that is my opinion, because `size()` is not an invalid position in the range `[beginning, end)` but `npos` is. The evidence is in the design of other containers: where is `npos` for vector? It doesn't have one; invalid indices are represented by `end`.

Comment: But with your solution I will have to write if( pos == str.length() ) which is extra memory access in client code instead of comparing with a constant. So I do not see your solution better, so did not creators of std::string interface. An your question can be translated to "why the world not the way I like it to be?" which is rhetorical.

Comment: @Slava that memory access is negligible and not a reason. Also you are ignoring the fact that with my solution, **you do not have to check at all in functions that take a range**, like erase or substr, but with yours you do. Mine -> less code, yours -> more code. Make sense? Anyhow, thanks for your answer.

Comment: @uk4321 `s.erase(s.find(...))` is invalid if find returns `size()` unless you have the 2nd (defaulted) parameter as `s.size()` (which you cannot do) or have another overload that assumes it.  The reason that overload was not added is because when they modified the interface for `string`, they added support for iterators, which already does what you are looking to do.

Comment: @ZacHowland remember in this conversation we are back in time before string was created. I know your answer which is just that they were ignorant.

Comment: @uk4321 no, it does not. It is just matter of taste, and it does not matter anyway as it is too late to change.

Comment: @uk4321 Reread what I just wrote.  It makes no assumptions about why they did not do that.  It is purely focused on what you would have to have in the interface to support what you are proposing, and also mentions why it was not added later.  And it is not that they were ignorant - they simply had a very different goal than what you do currently.  You are suffering from presentism.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that many member functions of std::basic_string use default arguments. That makes them more easier to use. For example consider the following constructor

```
basic_string(const basic_string& str, size_type pos, size_type n = npos,
const Allocator& a = Allocator());
```

What default argument could you specify for the third parameter n? The C++ Standard does not allow to use non-static members as default arguments:

> Similarly, a non-static member shall not be used in a default
>   argument, even if it is not evaluated, unless it appears as the
>   id-expression of a class member access expression (5.2.5) or unless it
>   is used to form a pointer to member

So npos is more convinient default argument.

Comment: As I mentioned elsewhere, you don't need default arguments to do this, you can use overloading.

Comment: @uk4321: How many functions are already part of the `std::basic_string` interface? [Hint > 75] Now consider that for each function that has one default argument you would have to create two overloads. That can affect the size of the binaries, the cost of compiling....

Comment: @David Most/all of it could be inlined anyway. Even if not, the cost would be negligible wouldn't it? But anyway, that raises the question of the bloat of the string interface which is for another day :)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Also there are only 15 functions which use npos as a default parameter by my count. That's a one-time cost of writing 15*4 = 60 _lines of code_ (assuming it's one line for function prototype, one line for body, one line for closing brace, and one blank line following), hardly a concern.